# Osmdroid - Polyline is not rendered smoothly

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am using Osmdroid library to display an offline map and I am using Polyline to draw line over the map. But resulting line is not continuous. If street is curved then the line is broken.

[image: example of broken line]

My code :

```
    Polyline polyline = new Polyline();
    ArrayList<GeoPoint> geoPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    // add Gepoint to array here.
    polyline.setPoints(geoPoints);
    polyline.setWidth(mywidth);
    polyline.setColor(mycolor);
    map.getOverlayManager().add(polyline);
    map.invalidate();
```

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify [Paint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) of the Polyline.

Paint has two attributes: stroke join and stroke cap. Stroke join controls how segments of a path are connected, stroke cap controls how whole path is ended.

Given that one can assume that this code would fix the problem:

```
polyline.getPaint().setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND)
```

**But it won't**. The Osmdroiod library apparently does some neat performance optimizations and doesn't render whole Polyline as one path. Instead it renders it in distinct segments. It's visual appearance can be improved by setting the stroke cap.

```
polyline.getPaint().setStrokeCap(Cap.Join.ROUND)
```

Comment: Hi Josef Adamcik . I am just trying add your code to my code, but it's not work.

Comment: @Foxes I see, I checked source of the osmdroid library and it appears there are some neat rendering optimizations that are causing this. Try to use `polyline.getPaint().setStrokeCap(Cap.ROUND);` instead, that shuuld do the trick and improve how your poliline looks. I will update my response accordingly.

Comment: I got it. Using polyline.getPaint().setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);   Tks for helps @Josef Adamcik. Please, share me the Osmdroid libs of you seen. I would like to know clearly.

Comment: Source code can be found on github, polyline class: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/fa144b43ba00229db99bc8244f4c3182bfed2aaa/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Polyline.java

Comment: getPaint is deprecated? any latest syntax?